# Conditional CXX_FLAGS using cmake based on compiler?

Tags: c++, cmake

I've just started using CMake for some personal and school projects, and I've been stumped by a minor issue.

Let's say I'm trying to get a C++ program compiling under multiple compilers (g++, cl, and bcc32 in this case). I have different command line switches for each compiler, and what I was attempting to do was to basically make a gnu/ms/borland directory and create CMake stuff in there (by entering the directories and doing a `cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++`
.. in the gnu, directory, for instance).

In the CMakeLists.txt on the top level directory, I tried doing something along the lines of:

```
if(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER STREQUAL g++)

  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wextra -Wall -ansi -pedantic")
```

And so on with elsifs for the other compilers, but this doesn't seem to work correctly -- it drops the `CXXFLAGS` entirely. The line works if I make the file completely unconditional (ie, just assume g++ and use g++ flags.).

What am I doing wrong here, or is there a better way to handle this sort of a problem?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are a bunch of [pre-defined CMake variables](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/Useful-Variables) depending on the compiler you're using:

```
if (MSVC)
  set ( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "/GLOBAL_FLAGS_GO_HERE")
  set ( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "/DEBUG_FLAGSS_GO_HERE")
  set ( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE  "/RELEASE_FLAGS_GO_HERE" )
endif ()

if (BORLAND)
  set ( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "/GLOBAL_FLAGS_GO_HERE")
  set ( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "/DEBUG_FLAGS_GO_HERE")
  set ( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE  "/RELEASE_FLAGS_GO_HERE" )
endif ()

if (CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
  set ( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "/GLOBAL_FLAGS_GO_HERE")
  set ( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "/DEBUG_FLAGS_GO_HERE")
  set ( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE  "/RELEASE_FLAGS_GO_HERE" )
endif ()
```

If you want your compiler options to override and persist in the generated CMakeCache:

```
if (CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)

  set ( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "/GLOBAL_FLAGS_GO_HERE" 
        CACHE STRING "g++ Compiler Flags for All Builds" FORCE)

  set ( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "/DEBUG_FLAGS_GO_HERE"
        CACHE STRING "g++ Compiler Flags for Debug Builds" FORCE)

  set ( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE  "/RELEASE_FLAGS_GO_HERE"
        CACHE STRING "g++ Compiler Flags for Release Builds" FORCE)

endif ()
```

Comment: Note, `CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX` is for g++ only. The OP asks for C++, right, but it's good to know there is also `CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC` to avoid confusions.