# CMake Fortran compiler-dependent flags

Tags: cmake, fortran

I'm using CMake for a moderate-sized Fortran project; sometimes I build it with gfortran, other times with ifort. When I want to do a debug build, the compiler flags are different; I'd like to have CMake automatically check which compiler is being used and set the flags accordingly.

It looks like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210839/conditional-cxx-flags-using-cmake-based-on-compiler) shows how to do the same thing for different C++ compilers. There's an [example](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMakeForFortranExample) of how to check compilers with Fortran, using

```
if (Fortran_COMPILER_NAME MATCHES "gfortran.*")
```

However, this fails to invoke the conditional, because CMake has decided to use `f95`. Of course, `f95` happens to alias to `gfortran`, but CMake doesn't detect that.

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use also use `CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER_ID`:

```
if ("${CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER_ID}" MATCHES "Intel")
  # something
elseif("${CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER_ID}" MATCHES "GNU")
  # something else
endif
```

Best way is to read file [CMakeDetermineFortranCompiler.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/CMakeDetermineFortranCompiler.cmake) and related files referenced from it.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than trying to special case for different compilers you should actually test that your compiler supports the flags you want to set using [`check_fortran_compiler_flag`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/module/CheckFortranCompilerFlag.html?highlight=check_fortran_compiler_flag) like so:

```
include(CheckFortranCompilerFlag)
check_fortran_compiler_flag("-my-flag" _my_flag)
if(_my_flag)
  set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS} -my-flag")
endif()
```

This is both safer and (I think) simpler because you don't need the implied knowledge of which compiler (and version) supports which flag.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Only indicate the full path of compiler installed e.g.gfortran. the code:  cmake -DCMAKE_fortran_PATH=/usr/bin/gfortran